# Core plot temperature gradient line

Tags: ios, core-plot

I would like to achieve gradient effect like in the attached image.[image]

I have tried to alter `lineGradient` of the `CPTMutableLineStyle` of the object. But couldn't reach to the same effect.

How would you do it?

Comment: If I were doing this myself, I would make the line the path of a CAShapeLayer and use it to mask a CAGradientLayer underneath that had the rainbow gradient. I don't know if you can apply this technique to core-plot or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `lineFill` property of the line style instead. You can use a gradient or an image to provide the fill pattern.

Comment: It doesn't work like so. It makes a gradient along the line. I need the gradient change only verticaly. As in the image.

Comment: I have found that lineStyle.lineFill  =   [CPTFill fillWithImage:image]; does the job. Where the image represents the gradient. Thanks Erik.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem @oleg-danu was probably having was not setting the angle on his gradient.  On the other hand, using an image fill seems to have weird clipping issues.  Building on @eric-skroch's answer:

```
CPTColor *red         = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
CPTColor *orange      = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor colorWithCrayola:@"Orange"].CGColor];
CPTGradient *gradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:red endingColor:orange];
gradient.angle        = 270.0; // This is critical for red at the top, orange at the bottom

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [plot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
lineStyle.lineWidth            = 3.0;
lineStyle.lineColor          = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
lineStyle.lineFill             = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:gradient];
plot.dataLineStyle             = lineStyle;
```

This line was created with a gradient:
[image: Line with gradient]

This line was created with an image and has clipping issues:
[image: Line with image]